# Defense against endless hordes

Tags: internal-consistency, military-defense

Imagine humans of the present day and an enemy who suddenly appeared (seemingly) out of nowhere. The enemy has following capabilities:

Their army consist of all kinds of creatures from kind of humanoid, through more animal like, to weird tentacled monsters. But are led by inteligent beings.

Endless supply of troops. It can be anything like monsters emerging from portals, or some new spieces of mutated animals that reproduces rapidly, or just being created from thin air. It is not important how exactly this is done, important is that humans have no chance standing against this enemy in open combat since any losses to humans would be much harder to replace than for the enemy.

Widely spread and fast army. Enemy can march in groups widely spread to say 500km in width and at constant speed 200km/h. They dont need to eat and almost never rest. Combined with their endless numbers, this makes them hard to destroy by missiles and airstrikes.

Their are only superior on land. They do have aquatic, aerial and subterranean creatures but these are far weaker and less in numbers than the main army and can be defeated by human submarines/aeroplanes. This forces them to always move their army on land. They can get through rivers like night king in game of thrones used his zombies to fill the burning trench, but not huge rivers and not any sea.

They start with 3 armies in USA, arabian peninsula and Australia, where they immediately conquer everything giving them free access to almost whole North America, Asia, Africa, Europe and Australia. Initialy humans try to fight them in a regular way by deploying army, but they soon find out that it is absolutely inefective. Also the enemy leaders can comunicate with each other on the other side of the world, so they do cooperate.

Now, what I would suggest for humans to do is to create a heavily defended walls to guard places that are hardly accesible for enemy and evacuate there. This means mostly peninsulas or places surrounded by big lakes. And literaly every island in the world, since those are not possible for enemy to take. Humans would just need to guard the shores for possible attack from the sea, but those will never be as devastating as attack on the land. By looking at world map I found these places:

Srilanka, Indonesia(Oceania), New Zealand, Madagascar, Scandinavia, Canadian Islands, Quebec, whole South and Central america since you only need to build defense in Panama, Baja California, Mediterranean sea islands, Italy, Spain, Florida, Korea, Kamchatka, Yamalian peninsula, Greenland, Iceland, Britain, Japan, Hainan, Socotra.

Would it be possible to build these? Humans would have enough time to do this, because enemy spends most of his time raiding and destroying everyhing. But is there enough build material, is there enough companies and tools to to that? Would those places be sufficient to feed all 7 bilion people? Given that human face threat like this, they would of course cooperate at much higher level and put away all conficts and personal interests, but would that be enough? Or is there a better strategy to face enemy like this?
Thanks a lot!!

Edit 1:

Hi. I dont realy want to go into details about the enemy, since they are pretty complex, but ill try to clear few things up. They can multiply in two ways and that is by simpy laying eggs and second by being spawned by the leaders. For the purpose of this question you can think of them as Zerg from Starcraft. And leaders being kind of brood queens and kind of warlocks from Warcraft. The more powerful the leader gets, the faster he can spawn. And the bigger the army is the faster it multiplies. The initial 3 armies are spawned in secret in the woods or sands and after being big enough, they coordinately attack all 3 at once. This secret spwaning is eventualy discovered by humans but when they start acting it is to late and the armies already count milions of creatures. Why they don't stop the wall building efforts? They simply dont know. No satelites no planes no nothing. So their stategy would be to destroy as much human infrastructure and production as possible. So when they conquer for example New York, they dont know that people started building a wall in Panama. This question in fact was not about how to fight the enemy. I was mostly about the posibilities of the proposed plan(building walls), so I added the reality-check tag. The question was more about how hard would that be for people. How fast can we build such walls. How many people would be needed to build and maintain such defense. Lets say that wall would have to be made from some hard metal, be at least 50m high and at least 5m thick. And most importantly if humanity can sustain itself in such conditions. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  You're asking a lot of questions on a service that's designed for a single, focused question per post.  You appear to be asking for a [tag:reality-check] (please read the tag wiki), but it feels like a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and I'm not sure any answer can actually justify its position.  (\*continued\*)

Comment: Your "enemy" is at odds with itself, being both (a) a coordinated attacker and (b) simply raiding. You can't have both (especially on this scale). What are the sizes of the starting armies? What is the rate of new enemy arrival? Is this a *Pacific Rim* type of thing? Most importantly, why is this question important? Worldbuilding (on-topic) is about the rules & systems of your world, storybuilding (off-topic) is about circumstances, action, and plot. This feels a lot like storybuilding, as the outcome is based on [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609).

Comment: Africa and South America are technically islands, due to the Suez and Panama canals

Comment: You have an enemy that is capable enough to portal-attack three locations simultaneously, but somehow cannot portal-attack islands? They can travel at 200 km/h, easily fast enough to defeat wall-building efforts, but squander that critical advantage by sitting around *raiding*? They roll over the armies of the world, and have infinite numbers, but are stopped by mere *walls*? None of these make sense.

Comment: @JBH: https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/comments/bqa482/wp_in_a_harsh_typical_postapocalyptic_world_a/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app

Comment: @DTCooper, Yeah, Reddit is a great place to pose open-ended questions.  SE's focus is strictly "practical," meaning the answer should be "useful" to more people than just the OP.  Thus the focus on worldbuilding rather than storybuilding.

Comment: @nzaman but the army starting at arabian peninsula takes everything around and gains access to both asia and africa. south america is the only human controled continent.

Comment: @user535733 they are stoped by walls and everything else that humans have. as they get grouped near walls. they are vunderable

Comment: The solution is to build Invulnerable towers that your enemy have to walk past but cannot attack, creating a reality version of a infinite Tower defense game.

Comment: This is in the VTR queue, but I can't vote for it yet.  This really does fall into the world of [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609).  If your story needs the world to successfully build walls, it can.  If you want a realistic analysis - *it's impossible to save 7B people.* It'd be hard to save 10M.  Walls take time to build and can be climbed.  People take time to move and must be fed.  Materials must be transported (islands are NOT easy to get a billion tons of concrete to).  Frankly, that 200kph number is a complete deal killer. Did you mean 2kph?

Comment: I want to underscore the problem with that 200kph number.  New York to Los Angeles is about 3,900 km.  It would take your monsters 19.5 HOURS to make the trip - and you want to load people and supplies onto ships and move them to islands where they can build 50m high (that's ENORMOUS!) walls around the islands.  My car's speedometer tops out at 140 kph and I need time to travel.  Yes, I get it that the monsters are starting in odd locations, but 80%-90% of the worldwide population is dead before the first ship can leave harbor.  Are you *really sure* you meant 200 kph?

Comment: The 200km/h number is the optimal speed when they are not disrupted by anything. When they come across a city or any kind of place defended by humans, they would have to stop, surround the place and take it. I wanted to give my humans at least a year until the enemy discovers that walls are being build. So maybe I can slow them down to 50-100km/h.

Comment: Additionaly, I didnt want to build wall around every island. Islands can be defended just by having some troops around whole shore. Walls are suppodes to be build only on land choke point separating peninsulas. Meaning Panama, Spain, Italy, Korea, Florida, Kamchatka, Scandinavia and Quebec

Comment: @Shadowzee thats exactly the kind of defense Im trying to create. The wall full of towers and artilery that destroys them as they try to climb the wall.

Comment: @user65070 That's nowhere near enough of a limitation.  They don't need to stop for traffic lights and won't be significantly impeded by other vehicles on the road. Literally, they can cross the entire country in 19.5 hours. Their speed must be a function of your story, not your story a function of their speed.  Most armies can't march more than 40-65 km in a day (and that might be a lot). Your critters can traverse that it 15 minutes. It's insurmountable. Building your wall around a city of substantial size would take ***years*** and you're ignoring how much land is required to feed everyone.

Comment: @user65070 Building a wall across the "choke point" of Florida would also take years.  If you really put every resource into it, it *might* take months (you have only days at 200 kph).  But you also need to move a substantial part of the U.S. into it, but only as much as farm/cattle land can support.  Almost everybody's dead.  This is an issue of narrative necessity.  Just choose to do it and ignore whether or not it's probable, possible, or realistic.

Comment: @JBH this is kind of answer Im looking for. I would accept this as No, you cant answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Eat the invaders.**

Make the invaders taste delicious when cooked in a light butter sauce.

How convenient for us that they don't eat, and they are seemingly baffled by high walls. This will make corralling and containing herds of them much easier.

Comment: Use as source material for fertilizer or fuel might work as well. Maybe also for plastics.

Answer (score 2):

**Kill the head and the body will die.**

I can think of a few ways.

1. **Kill the head.**. They are led by intelligent creatures.  Kill those creatures.  Or cut off communications between creatures and troops.  If not being driven to attack, these thing might not attack.  They are not hungry, no reason to be angry.  Maybe they will sit there.
2. **Get your own**.  Because ∞ - ∞ = 0.  Find out how they are made and make some.  Or co-opt one of the intelligent leaders and turn it against the others.  Or hack their control mechanism and fake instructions from the leader.
3. **Choke points.**. If you can cordon off or otherwise control spawn points, you can kill the monsters as they arrive.  There is a trick like this for Plants vs Zombies on the last endless level.
4. **Disease.**  Microbes own this world.  Maybe these monsters are susceptible?  If they are not ghosts or robots and are made of meat, maybe some disease can spread thru them and take them out.
5. **Energy source.**  They don't eat.  If this is zombie-lowth low scifi and you can hand wave where the energy to move is coming from, then this won't work.  If you need to explain how they move, you can go after how they move.  Which is going to be something interesting and possibly something humans tech can use too.

Comment: Infinity minus infinity only equals zero for infinities of the same size. My aleph-1 army will always best your aleph-0 one!

Comment: 1,2,3 are impossible due to how enemy works. 4 should also be enemys advantage because they are the masters of bioengineering, but maybe that makes them a little overpowered. 5 they should get energy from some biological process that dont require eating(or maybe they can eat dirt sometimes) like breathing, photosyntesis etc.